# In Meteor, is it possible to make an async function from a sync function (opposite of wrapAsync)?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, callback

I'm aware of how to use `Meteor.wrapAsync()`, to make a function that takes a callback or returns a promise usable as if it was synchronous.

Is it possible to do the opposite, and if so how? I have a server-side function that calls some Meteor stuff synchronously (inc collections and accounts). I'd like to be able to run it concurrently in a batch, using something like `p-all` or `async.js`, to process the items in an array and wait until finished.

The app is using Meteor 1.6.0.1.

Here's some code, which doesn't work, as "Meteor code must always run within a Fiber":

```
  const actions = entries.map(entry =>
    () => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      Meteor.defer(() => {
        try {
          const result = createUserFromEntry(entry, schoolId, creatorId, recordTypeId, signupYmd);
          resolve(result);
        } catch (exc) {
          reject(exc);
        }
      })
    )
  );
  Meteor.wrapAsync(callback =>
    pAll(actions, { concurrency: 8, stopOnError: false })
      .then(res => callback(null, res))
      .catch(err => callback(err, null))
  )();
```

Constructive suggestions of a different/proper way to achieve the same aim within Meteor are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

`Meteor.defer` requires the passed function to run within a fiber. This can be fixed using `Meteor.bindEnvironment`:

```js
Meteor.defer(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
  try {
    const result = createUserFromEntry(entry, schoolId, creatorId, recordTypeId, signupYmd);
    resolve(result);
  } catch (exc) {
    reject(exc);
  }
}))
```

The `p-all` function does not need to be wrapped as it's already async:

```js
Meteor.startup(async function () {
 const done = await pAll(actions, { concurrency: 8, stopOnError: false })
})
```

However, there is a nice candy that allows you to run async code in sync functions ,as long as you are in a fiber, using `Promise.await`:

```js
Meteor.startup(function () {
 const done = Promise.await(pAll(actions, { concurrency: 8, stopOnError: false }))
})
```

Note, that `Promise.await` is Meteor specific and only available on the server.